# When animating a UITableview's height, the scroll gesture recogniser stays the same size

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have searched far and wide for a solution to this but to no avail.

The problem I am having is when I animate a UITableView's height in my application, the scrollable area stays the same size. ie. If you tap and drag on the part of the tableview that has increased in height, nothing will happen - but if you tap and drag in the small original frame of the tableview it scrolls perfectly fine.

The code I use to animate the tableview is as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = extendedFrame;    
            self.tbl_body.frame = extendedFrame;                
        }];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the view you are resizing here? A `UITableView` itself (so this is a subclass), or a view that is holding your `UITableView`? I'm asking this because it is not obvious that your table is actually resizing and if you don't have much cells in it you might even not notice that. Just for test make the background color of table different than the color of its container.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I left out the most important part lol. I am extending the frame of the view as well as the tableview which is a sub view

Comment: If tbl_body (table view) is inside the view (self.view) and frame does not have origin of (0,0) then table will have an offset (for x and y of origin). At the end tables frame should be equal to its containers bounds...). Also make a test (NSLog) what the frames really are after the animation - if you are using autolayout things might be tricky when using frames. Did you make the different colors test?

Comment: Hi, yes I have logged the frame values as well as switched background colours to test if the frame and tableview frame are the same and everything is correct. It seems almost as if only the gesture recogniser has not increased it's frame. I don't use auto-layout as I do everything in code.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps this has something to do with the fact that the tableview is within a UIScrollView?

Comment: That is important piece of information right there. Because `UITableView` is also a subclass of `UIScrollView` itself so you have `UIScrollView` inside `UIScrollView`. Care should be taken in `UIScrollView` delegate methods (if used). And getting the thing to work exactly as you want take some tweaking of gesture recognizers.

Comment: Well the UITableview belongs to a sub-ViewController so the delegate is different to that of the UISrollView so the delegate methods do not conflict with each other. That said, I'm thinking perhaps I forgot to register it as a sub-ViewController and perhaps that is causing issues. I am at a different client today but will test when I get back.

Comment: I can confirm that this did not work :/

Comment: I have discovered a post regarding the same problem: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59755-weird-problem-with-a-gesture-recognizer-on-a-resized-view.html

but unfortunately the answer does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally solved this but still do not quite understand the issue.

The only way I could fix it was to set the frame to the extended frame on initiliazation, then resize it back to the minimized frame. Only then when it is extended is the gesture recogniser the correct size.

I know not perfect but I had to go with this for lack of a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark but... have you tried using completion block to reload the data?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.tbl_body.frame = extendedFrame;                
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self.tbl_body reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: Sorry the test server is down at the moment, will test this as soon as it is back up

Comment: I tested this and unfortunately it did not work for me